# Changing the background colour of an individual cell in a range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am working on a left hand menu for an Excel workbook. What I am trying to achieve is to have a setting that can change the background colour of the menu, range A1:A200 in all sheets. I can do this with the code below and it works fine, the issue is that one cell, the active sheet cell (text not related to the actual sheet name), has a different background colour to the rest. I can't figure out how to detect that cell and ensure that it has the AccentColour when the NewColour is selected, I was thinking of cycling through all cells but that seems like it would take a long time;

```
Private Sub ChangeMenuBackgroundColour()
'Procedure to change the background colour of the left hand menu

    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cursheet As Worksheet
    Dim NewColour As Long
    Dim CurrentColour As String

    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

    CurrentColour = Range("Menu_Background_Colour").Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Select Case CurrentColour

        Case "Black"
            NewColour = RGB(50, 50, 50)
            AccentColour = RGB(75, 85, 95)

        Case "Blue"
            NewColour = RGB(55, 95, 145)
            AccentColour = RGB(80, 130, 190)

        Case "Brown"
            NewColour = RGB(90, 65, 50)
            AccentColour = RGB(115, 100, 95)

        Case "Green"
            NewColour = RGB(80, 130, 95)
            AccentColour = RGB(105, 190, 140)

        Case "Grey"
            NewColour = RGB(90, 90, 90)
            AccentColour = RGB(115, 125, 135)

        Case "Orange"
            NewColour = RGB(220, 120, 60)
            AccentColour = RGB(245, 145, 105)

        Case "Purple"
            NewColour = RGB(125, 75, 135)
            AccentColour = RGB(150, 110, 180)

        Case "Red"
            NewColour = RGB(180, 65, 65)
            AccentColour = RGB(205, 100, 110)

    End Select

    For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets

        If Not wsSheet.Name = "Blank" Then
            wsSheet.Activate

            With ActiveSheet

                Range("A1:A200").Interior.Color = NewColour

            End With

        End If

    Next wsSheet

    CurrentSheet.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: And adding `ActiveCell.Interior.Color = AccentColour` after `End with` isn't enough?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber The Active Cell would not be the correct one to have the AccentColour

Comment: Then what cell should have it?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber In the initial state the range A1:500 will have 499 dark blue cells and 1 light blue cell. So when the code runs it must change the dark blue cells to the new chosen colour and the light blue cell to the accent colour.

Comment: So it's a random cell in the range? It's probably easiest to loop them. It shouldn't take a long time at all.

Comment: I was thinking of that but I think it will take a while. I am pursuing a Find and Replace procedure instead (I think)